# I18n.t instead of hard value results in a different url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

This results in a link with the url "/users/sign_out". When I replace this with i18n like this:

```
<%= link_to I18n.t :logout_link, destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

It results in a link with the right text, but the url is "site/index", which is my root_path. Why is this going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this:

```
<%= link_to I18n.t(:logout_link), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: This works thanks. I like to add the l18n because then I know immediately it is a translation thing, instead of just a "t", which is confusing.